# SolrNet - Adding to existing index

Tags: import, solr, indexing, solrnet

I have a Solr server setup successfully with working searching and indexing capabilties.
There is about 380 documents in it after a full-import from my database.

Since running a full import each time will be quite time consuming once the amount of documents rise i am looking to SolrNet to make it easier to add/edit/delete documents in the Solr index.

So Solr has an index imported from my database. In my webservice im using SolrNet and here i have a method that adds something new to the index. After it's added it seems its the only thing in the index, all the "old" data that was imported is now gone.

Question 1: Can SolrNet ask Solr for a full-import again? (basicly calling this command: /solr/dataimport?command=full-import)

Question 2: Is SolrNet supposed to be able to CRUD to an excisting Index without wiping the old data? Im using this POC code to test it: http://pastebin.com/4G1YZ6Ah if so can you give me a clue as to what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Data import handler commands are not currently implemented in SolrNet ([issue here](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/detail?id=78)) but you can just call the DIH command with a simple [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx).
2. When you call Add() in SolrNet you add just that document. It does not wipe the index or anything like that. Your issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Im guessing the issue isnt with Solrnet then? Do you have any idea or clue as to what might cause this behaviour in Solr?

Comment: @mfriis: start from a known good state (i.e. the SolrNet sample app) and work step-by-step from there.